# Using SSIS to import NOAA Data

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, ssis, xsd

I am trying to use SSIS to load data from an xml file to a sql table. On the xml source adapter I keep getting the XML Source Adapter does not support mixed content model on complex types. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the xml and xsd (note I edited some data so it would fit in this message):

EDIT: xml link: http://sdrv.ms/11KcWas

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dwml version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/schema/DWML.xsd">
  <head>
    <product srsName="WGS 1984" concise-name="time-series" operational-mode="official">
      <title>NOAA's National Weather Service Real Time Mesoscale Analysis And Forecast Data</title>
      <field>meteorological</field>
      <category>analysis and forecast</category>
      <creation-date refresh-frequency="PT1H">2013-06-06T19:26:37Z</creation-date>
    </product>
    <source>
      <more-information>http://products.weather.gov/search.php</more-information>
      <production-center>Meteorological Development Laboratory<sub-center>Product Generation Branch</sub-center></production-center>
      <disclaimer>http://www.nws.noaa.gov/disclaimer.html</disclaimer>
      <credit>http://www.weather.gov/</credit>
      <credit-logo>http://www.weather.gov/images/xml_logo.gif</credit-logo>
      <feedback>http://www.weather.gov/feedback.php</feedback>
    </source>
  </head>
  <data>
    <location>
      <location-key>point1</location-key>
      <point latitude="45.00" longitude="-105.00"/>
    </location>
    <moreWeatherInformation applicable-location="point1">http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?textField1=45.00&amp;textField2=-105.00</moreWeatherInformation>
    <time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="none">
      <layout-key>k-p24h-n3-1</layout-key>
      <start-valid-time>2013-06-06T08:00:00-06:00</start-valid-time>
      <end-valid-time>2013-06-06T20:00:00-06:00</end-valid-time>

    </time-layout>
    <time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="none">
      <layout-key>k-p24h-n2-2</layout-key>
      <start-valid-time>2013-06-06T20:00:00-06:00</start-valid-time>
      <end-valid-time>2013-06-07T09:00:00-06:00</end-valid-time>
      <start-valid-time>2013-06-07T20:00:00-06:00</start-valid-time>
      <end-valid-time>2013-06-08T09:00:00-06:00</end-valid-time>
    </time-layout>
    <time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="none">
      <layout-key>k-p12h-n5-3</layout-key>
      <start-valid-time>2013-06-06T06:00:00-06:00</start-valid-time>
      <end-valid-time>2013-06-06T18:00:00-06:00</end-valid-time>
    </time-layout>
    <time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="none">
      <layout-key>k-p3h-n17-4</layout-key>
      <start-valid-time>2013-06-06T15:00:00-06:00</start-valid-time>

    </time-layout>
    <time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="none">
      <layout-key>k-p6h-n9-5</layout-key>
      <start-valid-time>2013-06-06T12:00:00-06:00</start-valid-time>
      <end-valid-time>2013-06-06T18:00:00-06:00</end-valid-time>

    </time-layout>
    <time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="none">
      <layout-key>k-p6h-n5-6</layout-key>
      <start-valid-time>2013-06-06T12:00:00-06:00</start-valid-time>
      <end-valid-time>2013-06-06T18:00:00-06:00</end-valid-time>

    </time-layout>
    <time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="none">
      <layout-key>k-p1h-n49-7</layout-key>
      <start-valid-time>2013-06-06T15:00:00-06:00</start-valid-time>

    </time-layout>
    <time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="none">
      <layout-key>k-p24h-n3-8</layout-key>
      <start-valid-time>2013-06-06T12:00:00-06:00</start-valid-time>
      <end-valid-time>2013-06-07T06:00:00-06:00</end-valid-time>
      <start-valid-time>2013-06-07T06:00:00-06:00</start-valid-time>
      <end-valid-time>2013-06-08T06:00:00-06:00</end-valid-time>
      <start-valid-time>2013-06-08T06:00:00-06:00</start-valid-time>
      <end-valid-time>2013-06-09T06:00:00-06:00</end-valid-time>
    </time-layout>
    <time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="none">
      <layout-key>k-p24h-n1-9</layout-key>
      <start-valid-time>2013-06-06T10:00:00-06:00</start-valid-time>
      <end-valid-time>2013-06-07T06:00:00-06:00</end-valid-time>
    </time-layout>
    <time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="none">
      <layout-key>k-p24h-n2-10</layout-key>
      <start-valid-time>2013-06-07T06:00:00-06:00</start-valid-time>
      <end-valid-time>2013-06-08T06:00:00-06:00</end-valid-time>
      <start-valid-time>2013-06-08T06:00:00-06:00</start-valid-time>
      <end-valid-time>2013-06-09T06:00:00-06:00</end-valid-time>
    </time-layout>
    <time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="none">
      <layout-key>k-p1m-n1-11</layout-key>
      <start-valid-time>2013-05-31T18:00:00-06:00</start-valid-time>
      <end-valid-time>2013-06-30T18:00:00-06:00</end-valid-time>
    </time-layout>
    <time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="none">
      <layout-key>k-p3m-n1-12</layout-key>
      <start-valid-time>2013-05-31T18:00:00-06:00</start-valid-time>
      <end-valid-time>2013-08-31T18:00:00-06:00</end-valid-time>
    </time-layout>
    <parameters applicable-location="point1">
      <temperature type="maximum" units="Fahrenheit" time-layout="k-p24h-n3-1">
        <name>Daily Maximum Temperature</name>
        <value>73</value>
        <value>79</value>
        <value>72</value>
      </temperature>
      <temperature type="minimum" units="Fahrenheit" time-layout="k-p24h-n2-2">
        <name>Daily Minimum Temperature</name>
        <value>51</value>
        <value>56</value>
      </temperature>
      <temperature type="hourly" units="Fahrenheit" time-layout="k-p3h-n17-4">
        <name>Temperature</name>
        <value>72</value>
        <value>71</value>
        <value>63</value>
        <value>57</value>
        <value>53</value>
        <value>52</value>
        <value>67</value>
        <value>76</value>
        <value>78</value>
        <value>77</value>
        <value>69</value>
        <value>63</value>
        <value>59</value>
        <value>56</value>
        <value>67</value>
        <value>68</value>
        <value>72</value>
      </temperature>
      <temperature type="dew point" units="Fahrenheit" time-layout="k-p3h-n17-4">
        <name>Dew Point Temperature</name>
        <value>43</value>
        <value>42</value>
        <value>44</value>
        <value>46</value>
        <value>46</value>
        <value>46</value>
        <value>47</value>
        <value>47</value>
        <value>46</value>
        <value>46</value>
        <value>48</value>
        <value>49</value>
        <value>49</value>
        <value>48</value>
        <value>47</value>
        <value>45</value>
        <value>44</value>
      </temperature>
      <precipitation type="liquid" units="inches" time-layout="k-p6h-n9-5">
        <name>Liquid Precipitation Amount</name>
        <value>0.00</value>
        <value>0.00</value>
        <value>0.00</value>
        <value>0.00</value>
        <value>0.01</value>
        <value>0.02</value>
        <value>0.01</value>
        <value>0.00</value>
        <value>0.00</value>
      </precipitation>
      <wind-speed type="sustained" units="knots" time-layout="k-p3h-n17-4">
        <name>Wind Speed</name>
        <value>5</value>
        <value>7</value>
        <value>6</value>
        <value>5</value>
        <value>6</value>
        <value>7</value>
        <value>7</value>
        <value>7</value>
        <value>5</value>
        <value>4</value>
        <value>6</value>
        <value>9</value>
        <value>11</value>
        <value>10</value>
        <value>15</value>
        <value>18</value>
        <value>16</value>
      </wind-speed>
      <direction type="wind" units="degrees true" time-layout="k-p3h-n17-4">
        <name>Wind Direction</name>
        <value>340</value>
        <value>10</value>
        <value>100</value>
        <value>190</value>
        <value>180</value>
        <value>180</value>
        <value>200</value>
        <value>220</value>
        <value>220</value>
        <value>220</value>
        <value>230</value>
        <value>230</value>
        <value>260</value>
        <value>280</value>
        <value>300</value>
        <value>310</value>
        <value>310</value>
      </direction>
      <cloud-amount type="total" units="percent" time-layout="k-p3h-n17-4">
        <name>Cloud Cover Amount</name>
        <value>25</value>
        <value>37</value>
        <value>36</value>
        <value>35</value>
        <value>36</value>
        <value>37</value>
        <value>42</value>
        <value>47</value>
        <value>57</value>
        <value>67</value>
        <value>66</value>
        <value>65</value>
        <value>61</value>
        <value>57</value>
        <value>58</value>
        <value>50</value>
        <value>49</value>
      </cloud-amount>
      <water-state time-layout="k-p6h-n9-5">
        <waves type="significant" units="feet">
          <name>Wave Height</name>
          <value xsi:nil="true"/>
          <value xsi:nil="true"/>
          <value xsi:nil="true"/>
          <value xsi:nil="true"/>
          <value xsi:nil="true"/>
          <value xsi:nil="true"/>
          <value xsi:nil="true"/>
          <value xsi:nil="true"/>
          <value xsi:nil="true"/>
        </waves>
      </water-state>
      <precipitation type="snow" units="inches" time-layout="k-p6h-n5-6">
        <name>Snow Amount</name>
        <value>0.00</value>
        <value>0.00</value>
        <value>0.00</value>
        <value>0.00</value>
        <value>0.00</value>
      </precipitation>
      <precipitation type="ice" units="inches" time-layout="k-p6h-n5-6">
        <name>Ice Accumulation</name>
        <value>0.00</value>
        <value>0.00</value>
        <value>0.00</value>
        <value>0.00</value>
        <value>0.00</value>
      </precipitation>
      <probability-of-precipitation type="12 hour" units="percent" time-layout="k-p12h-n5-3">
        <name>12 Hourly Probability of Precipitation</name>
        <value>2</value>
        <value>6</value>
        <value>18</value>
        <value>30</value>
        <value>13</value>
      </probability-of-precipitation>
      <wind-speed type="cumulative64" units="percent" time-layout="k-p6h-n9-5">
        <name>Probability of a Tropical Cyclone Wind Speed above 64 Knots (Cumulative)</name>
        <value xsi:nil="true"/>
        <value xsi:nil="true"/>
        <value xsi:nil="true"/>
        <value xsi:nil="true"/>
        <value xsi:nil="true"/>
        <value xsi:nil="true"/>
        <value xsi:nil="true"/>
        <value xsi:nil="true"/>
        <value xsi:nil="true"/>
      </wind-speed>
      <fire-weather type="risk from wind and relative humidity" time-layout="k-p24h-n3-8">
        <name>Fire Weather Outlook from Wind and Relative Humidity</name>
        <value>No Areas</value>
        <value>No Areas</value>
        <value>No Areas</value>
      </fire-weather>
      <fire-weather type="risk from dry thunderstorms" time-layout="k-p24h-n2-2">
        <name>Fire Weather Outlook from Dry Thunderstorms</name>
        <value>No Areas</value>
        <value>No Areas</value>
      </fire-weather>
      <convective-hazard>
        <outlook time-layout="k-p24h-n3-8">
          <name>Convective Hazard Outlook</name>
          <value>No Thunderstorms</value>
          <value>General Thunderstorms</value>
          <value>General Thunderstorms</value>
        </outlook>
      </convective-hazard>
      <convective-hazard>
        <severe-component type="tornadoes" units="percent" time-layout="k-p24h-n1-9">
          <name>Probability of Tornadoes</name>
          <value>0</value>
        </severe-component>
      </convective-hazard>
      <convective-hazard>
        <severe-component type="hail" units="percent" time-layout="k-p24h-n1-9">
          <name>Probability of Hail</name>
          <value>0</value>
        </severe-component>
      </convective-hazard>
      <convective-hazard>
        <severe-component type="damaging thunderstorm winds" units="percent" time-layout="k-p24h-n1-9">
          <name>Probability of Damaging Thunderstorm Winds</name>
          <value>0</value>
        </severe-component>
      </convective-hazard>
      <convective-hazard>
        <severe-component type="extreme tornadoes" units="percent" time-layout="k-p24h-n1-9">
          <name>Probability of Extreme Tornadoes</name>
          <value>0</value>
        </severe-component>
      </convective-hazard>
      <convective-hazard>
        <severe-component type="extreme hail" units="percent" time-layout="k-p24h-n1-9">
          <name>Probability of Extreme Hail</name>
          <value>0</value>
        </severe-component>
      </convective-hazard>
      <convective-hazard>
        <severe-component type="extreme thunderstorm winds" units="percent" time-layout="k-p24h-n1-9">
          <name>Probability of Extreme Thunderstorm Winds</name>
          <value>0</value>
        </severe-component>
      </convective-hazard>
      <convective-hazard>
        <severe-component type="severe thunderstorms" units="percent" time-layout="k-p24h-n2-10">
          <name>Total Probability of Severe Thunderstorms</name>
          <value>0</value>
          <value>0</value>
        </severe-component>
      </convective-hazard>
      <convective-hazard>
        <severe-component type="extreme severe thunderstorms" units="percent" time-layout="k-p24h-n2-10">
          <name>Total Probability of Extreme Severe Thunderstorms</name>
          <value>0</value>
          <value>0</value>
        </severe-component>
      </convective-hazard>
      <climate-anomaly>
        <monthly type="average temperature above normal" units="percent" time-layout="k-p1m-n1-11">
          <name>Probability of One-Month Average Temperature Above Normal</name>
          <value>33</value>
        </monthly>
      </climate-anomaly>
      <climate-anomaly>
        <monthly type="average temperature below normal" units="percent" time-layout="k-p1m-n1-11">
          <name>Probability of One-Month Average Temperature Below Normal</name>
          <value>33</value>
        </monthly>
      </climate-anomaly>
      <climate-anomaly>
        <monthly type="average precipitation above normal" units="percent" time-layout="k-p1m-n1-11">
          <name>Probability of One-Month Average Precipitation Above Normal</name>
          <value>34</value>
        </monthly>
      </climate-anomaly>
      <climate-anomaly>
        <monthly type="average precipitation below normal" units="percent" time-layout="k-p1m-n1-11">
          <name>Probability of One-Month Average Precipitation Below Normal</name>
          <value>33</value>
        </monthly>
      </climate-anomaly>
      <climate-anomaly>
        <seasonal type="average temperature above normal" units="percent" time-layout="k-p3m-n1-12">
          <name>Probability of Three-Month Average Temperature Above Normal</name>
          <value>39</value>
        </seasonal>
      </climate-anomaly>
      <climate-anomaly>
        <seasonal type="average temperature below normal" units="percent" time-layout="k-p3m-n1-12">
          <name>Probability of Three-Month Average Temperature Below Normal</name>
          <value>27</value>
        </seasonal>
      </climate-anomaly>
      <climate-anomaly>
        <seasonal type="average precipitation above normal" units="percent" time-layout="k-p3m-n1-12">
          <name>Probability of Three-Month Average Precipitation Above Normal</name>
          <value>33</value>
        </seasonal>
      </climate-anomaly>
      <hazards time-layout="k-p1h-n49-7">
        <name>Watches, Warnings, and Advisories</name>
      </hazards>
      <wind-speed type="incremental34" units="percent" time-layout="k-p6h-n9-5">
        <name>Probability of a Tropical Cyclone Wind Speed above 34 Knots (Incremental)</name>

      </wind-speed>
      <wind-speed type="incremental50" units="percent" time-layout="k-p6h-n9-5">
        <name>Probability of a Tropical Cyclone Wind Speed above 50 Knots (Incremental)</name>

      </wind-speed>
      <wind-speed type="incremental64" units="percent" time-layout="k-p6h-n9-5">
        <name>Probability of a Tropical Cyclone Wind Speed above 64 Knots (Incremental)</name>

      </wind-speed>
      <wind-speed type="cumulative34" units="percent" time-layout="k-p6h-n9-5">
        <name>Probability of a Tropical Cyclone Wind Speed above 34 Knots (Cumulative)</name>

      </wind-speed>
      <wind-speed type="cumulative50" units="percent" time-layout="k-p6h-n9-5">
        <name>Probability of a Tropical Cyclone Wind Speed above 50 Knots (Cumulative)</name>

      </wind-speed>
      <humidity type="relative" units="percent" time-layout="k-p3h-n17-4">
        <name>Relative Humidity</name>
        <value>35</value>
        <value>35</value>
        <value>50</value>
        <value>66</value>
        <value>77</value>
        <value>80</value>
        <value>49</value>
        <value>36</value>
        <value>32</value>
        <value>33</value>
        <value>47</value>
        <value>60</value>
        <value>69</value>
        <value>74</value>
        <value>49</value>
        <value>44</value>
        <value>37</value>
      </humidity>
      <temperature type="apparent" units="Fahrenheit" time-layout="k-p3h-n17-4">
        <name>Apparent Temperature</name>
        <value>72</value>
        <value>71</value>
        <value>63</value>
        <value>57</value>
        <value>53</value>
        <value>52</value>
        <value>67</value>
        <value>76</value>
        <value>78</value>
        <value>77</value>
        <value>69</value>
        <value>63</value>
        <value>59</value>
        <value>56</value>
        <value>67</value>
        <value>68</value>
        <value>72</value>
      </temperature>
      <wind-speed type="gust" units="knots" time-layout="k-p3h-n17-4">
        <name>Wind Speed Gust</name>
        <value>6</value>
        <value>7</value>
        <value>6</value>
        <value>5</value>
        <value>6</value>
        <value>7</value>
        <value>8</value>
        <value>7</value>
        <value>6</value>
        <value>5</value>
        <value>6</value>
        <value>9</value>
        <value>16</value>
        <value>14</value>
        <value>21</value>
        <value>25</value>
        <value>22</value>
      </wind-speed>
      <weather time-layout="k-p3h-n17-4">
        <name>Weather Type, Coverage, and Intensity</name>

          <value coverage="slight chance" intensity="none" weather-type="thunderstorms" qualifier="none">
            <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
          </value>
          <value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" additive="and" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
            <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
          </value>
        </weather-conditions>
        <weather-conditions>
          <value coverage="slight chance" intensity="none" weather-type="thunderstorms" qualifier="none">
            <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
          </value>
          <value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" additive="and" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
            <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
          </value>
        </weather-conditions>
        <weather-conditions>
          <value coverage="chance" intensity="none" weather-type="thunderstorms" qualifier="none">
            <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
          </value>
          <value coverage="chance" intensity="light" additive="and" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
            <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
          </value>
        </weather-conditions>
        <weather-conditions>
          <value coverage="chance" intensity="none" weather-type="thunderstorms" qualifier="none">
            <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
          </value>
          <value coverage="chance" intensity="light" additive="and" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
            <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
          </value>
        </weather-conditions>
        <weather-conditions>
          <value coverage="slight chance" intensity="none" weather-type="thunderstorms" qualifier="none">
            <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
          </value>
          <value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" additive="and" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
            <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
          </value>
        </weather-conditions>
        <weather-conditions>
          <value coverage="slight chance" intensity="none" weather-type="thunderstorms" qualifier="none">
            <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
          </value>
          <value coverage="slight chance" intensity="light" additive="and" weather-type="rain showers" qualifier="none">
            <visibility xsi:nil="true"/>
          </value>
        </weather-conditions>
        <weather-conditions/>
        <weather-conditions/>
        <weather-conditions/>
        <weather-conditions/>
      </weather>
      <conditions-icon type="forecast-NWS" time-layout="k-p3h-n17-4">
        <name>Conditions Icons</name>
      </conditions-icon>
      <climate-anomaly>
        <seasonal type="average precipitation below normal" units="percent" time-layout="k-p3m-n1-12">
          <name>Probability of Three-Month Average Precipitation Below Normal</name>
          <value>33</value>
        </seasonal>
      </climate-anomaly>
    </parameters>
  </data>
</dwml>



<!--

-->
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:include schemaLocation="http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/schema/meta_data.xsd"/>
<xsd:include schemaLocation="http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/schema/ndfd_data.xsd"/>
<xsd:simpleType name="latLonListType">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
This expression enforces a space delimited list of latitude longitude pairs. The latitude and longitude values are delimited by a comma (i.e. 38.00,-100.00 40.00,-78.00)
</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:pattern value="[\-]?\d{1,2}\.\d+,[\-]?\d{1,3}\.\d+( [\-]?\d{1,2}\.\d+,[\-]?\d{1,3}\.\d+)*"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="cityNameListType">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
This expression enforces a coma delimited list city names. The city names are ordered to match the cities latitude and longitude value in the accompanying latLonListType element (i.e. Dallas,Los Angeles,Salt Lake City)
</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:pattern value="[a-zA-Z'\-]*( ?[a-zA-Z'\-]*)*,[A-Z][A-Z](\|[a-zA-Z'\-]*( ?[a-zA-Z'\-]*)*,[A-Z][A-Z])*"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:element name="dwml">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:choice>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="head" type="headType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="data" type="dataType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xsd:keyref name="applicable-locationKey" refer="locationKey">
<xsd:selector xpath="data/parameters"/>
<xsd:field xpath="@applicable-location"/>
</xsd:keyref>
<xsd:keyref name="moreWeatherInformationKey" refer="locationKey">
<xsd:selector xpath="data/moreWeatherInformation"/>
<xsd:field xpath="@applicable-location"/>
</xsd:keyref>
<xsd:keyref name="applicable-timeKey" refer="timeKey">
<xsd:selector xpath="data/parameters/*"/>
<xsd:field xpath="@time-layout"/>
</xsd:keyref>
<xsd:keyref name="applicable-categoriesKey" refer="categoriesKey">
<xsd:selector xpath="data/parameters/*"/>
<xsd:field xpath="@applicable-categories"/>
</xsd:keyref>
<xsd:key name="locationKey">
<xsd:selector xpath=".//location"/>
<xsd:field xpath="location-key"/>
</xsd:key>
<xsd:key name="timeKey">
<xsd:selector xpath=".//time-layout"/>
<xsd:field xpath="layout-key"/>
</xsd:key>
<xsd:key name="categoriesKey">
<xsd:selector xpath=".//categories"/>
<xsd:field xpath="categories-key"/>
</xsd:key>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="minResolution" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xsd:element name="latLonList" type="latLonListType"/>
<xsd:element name="cityNameList" type="cityNameListType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:choice>
<xsd:attribute name="version" type="xsd:string" default="1.0"/>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is exactly what it says: the data source you are using does not support mixed content in elements. The mixed content is defined in the http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/schema/meta_data.xsd schema referenced from the schema you included.
A quick Google suggests you need to use XPATH to extract the specific data points of interest (or, if possible, use a different schema).
That can be done by bulk loading the XML into a field in the database and using SQL Server XML processing to do your ETL (effectively relegating SSIS to reading the XML file and dropping it in to the database for a stored procedure to do all the work) or by writing a script task in C# or VB.NET that takes the XML sources and uses the .NET Framework XML libraries to parse it into the columns you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is invalid. I recommend that you validate it.

You have a ending`</weather-conditions>` on line 475 but no beginning tag. I suspect that your problems all stem from errors in the XML.

Comment: That was probably me editing the code so it can fit within the 30000 character count limit. I validated it against http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp and it checked out ok.

Comment: @user1389739 the snippet that you posted does not validate and seems to have a missing beginning </weather-condition> tag.